# Export Datagridview Data to access database

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I imort all tables from excel file to datagridview in vb.net. Then I remove certain columns of/in datagrid view. Now I want this new data of datagridview to be exported to access database (.accdb) which is already created.

I searhced internet but didnt find the solution.

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Public Class epunjabdataimport
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dts As DataSet
    Dim excel As String
    Dim openfileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
    Private myConString As String
    Private cn1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try

            OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
            openfileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
            If openfileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(openfileDialog.FileName)
                Dim FileName As String = openfileDialog.FileName
                excel = fi.FullName
                conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
                dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [List_of_Student_Data$]", conn)
                '  dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select colmun3 as 'Student_Name', column4 as 'Father_Name', column10 as 'Class_Name', column11 as 'Section', Column21 as 'Admission_No', Column29 as 'Roll_No' from [List_of_Student_Data$]", conn)


                dts = New DataSet
                dta.Fill(dts, "[List_of_Student_Data$]")
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
                DataGridView1.DataMember = "[List_of_Student_Data$]"
                conn.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        Try

            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(1)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(3)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(3)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(3)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(3)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(3)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(5)

            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)

            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)

            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(7)
            DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(7)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)

            With DataGridView1
                .RowHeadersVisible = False
                .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "SNo"
                .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Student_Name"
                .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Father_Name"
                .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Class_Name"
                .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Section"
                .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Admission_No"
                .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Roll_No"
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub   

    Private Sub Epunjabdataimport_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim directory As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\callsec.accdb"
        myConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + directory + "; Persist Security Info=False;"
        cn1.ConnectionString = myConString

    End Sub


End Class
```

I want code so that on a click of a button all data of datagridview be inserted/exported to access database.

Comment: Excel is irrelevant and so is the `DataGridView`.  You have a `DataTable` and you want to save its contents to a database.  That's all that matters.  To do that, you need a data adapter with an appropriate `InsertCommand`.  When you `Fill` the `DataTable` in the first place, be sure to set the `AcceptChangesOnFill` property of that data adapter to `False`.  That way, every `DataRow` will have a `RowState` of `Added` and be ready to be inserted.

Comment: Note that you can actually use a single `OleDbDataAdapter` here.  The `SelectCommand` and the `InsertCommand` can each have a different connection, so you can simply set up that data adapter, call `Fill`, call `Update` au're done.

Comment: Why are you removing all those columns from the grid anyway?  If you don;t want all the columns, don't retrieve them in the first place.  If you don;t want to retrieve every column from your data source, don't use `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below, you can load, add, save, and delete records between a DataGridView and an Access table.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim sCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim sDs As DataSet
    Dim sTable As DataTable

    Private Sub load_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles load_btn.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Stores"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        sCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
        sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
        sDs = New DataSet()
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Stores")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    End Sub

    Private Sub new_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles new_btn.Click
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = False
        save_btn.Enabled = True
        new_btn.Enabled = False
        delete_btn.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub delete_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles delete_btn.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
            sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click
        sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        new_btn.Enabled = True
        delete_btn.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

After you create a DataTable with data you want to save.
Create new DataAdapter and CommandBuilder for said Adapter, then simply send update command. As there is no previous data, it will treat it as new rows for the specified table in the database.

Some pseudocode:

```
 Adapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & TableName, Database_Connection)
 DB_DataBuilder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(Adapter)
 DB_DataBuilder.QuotePrefix = "["
 DB_DataBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
 DB_Adapter.Update(DataTable)
```

If you need to create a Table in the Database as well, then do open the connection to database and using dbcomand "CREATE TABLE" make a table with [column name] DATA TYPE of your choosing.

```
   DB_Connection.Open()
   Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = DB_Connection
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [" & TableName & "]([Column1] TEXT, [Column2] DATETIME, [Column3] INTEGER)"
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'MessageBox.Show("Table " & TableName & " created.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
    DB_Connection.Close()
```